Are there mathematically different but physically equivalent density operators?
Quantum states related by a global phase shift are physically equivalent. However, pure quantum states related by a global phase shift lead to the same density operator:
$$ |{\psi}\rangle= |{1}\rangle \rightarrow \rho=|{1} \rangle\langle{1}|$$
$$ |{\psi^\prime}\rangle= e^{i\theta}|{1}\rangle \rightarrow \rho^\prime= e^{i\theta} |{1} \rangle\langle{1}| e^{-i\theta}=|{1} \rangle\langle{1}| $$
Hence the question: are there density operators which are mathematically different but physically equivalent?

Did you not just name examples?

@MattHanson No, they didn't (as far as I understand the question): Both operators corresponding to the different wave functions are equal, i.e. the same operator (and not "mathematically different"). I read the question as: "Are there two distinct density operators which give the same predictions?" and the answer to that question is the linked PSE thread.

The question is not well posed, as pure states  are not vectors, but just unit vectors up to phases. However, in the presence of super selection rules there are examples of density operators giving rise to identical predictions on the observables of the theory.
